# Winforms TableLayoutPanel adding rows programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, runtime, tablelayoutpanel

I've been fighting with this for a while, and have found that a number of other people struggle with the TableLayoutPanel (.net 2.0 Winforms) as well.

**Problem**

I am attempting to take a 'blank' tablelayoutpanel, which has 10 columns defined, then at runtime programmatically add rows of controls (i.e. one control per cell).

One might have thought that it should be as simple as

```
myTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(myControl, 0 /* Column Index */, 0 /* Row index */);
```

But that (for me) doesn't add the rows. So maybe adding in a row style

```
myTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Clear();
myTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30F));
```

But that doesn't work either. I've dug around and found out that the `myTableLayoutPanel.RowCount` usage changes from design time to run time, hence doing `myTableLayoutPanel.RowCount++;` doesn't actually add another row, not even before/after adding a RowStyle entry for it!

Another related issue I am encountering is that the controls will be added to the display, but they all simply get rendered at point 0,0 of the TableLayoutPanel, additionally they are not even constrained to be within the Cell bounds that they are supposed to be displayed within (i.e. with Dock = DockStyle.Fill they still appear way too large/small).

Does someone have a working example of adding rows & controls at runtime?

Comment: Adding a RowStyle will actually increase the RowStyles.Count()

Answer (score 74):

I just did this last week. Set the `GrowStyle` on the `TableLayoutPanel` to `AddRows` or `AddColumns`, then your code should work:

```
// Adds "myControl" to the first column of each row
myTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(myControl1, 0 /* Column Index */, 0 /* Row index */);
myTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(myControl2, 0 /* Column Index */, 1 /* Row index */);
myTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(myControl3, 0 /* Column Index */, 2 /* Row index */);
```

Here is some working code that seems similar to what you are doing:

```
    private Int32 tlpRowCount = 0;

    private void BindAddress()
    {
        Addlabel(Addresses.Street);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Addresses.Street2))
        {
            Addlabel(Addresses.Street2);
        }
        Addlabel(Addresses.CityStateZip);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Account.Country))
        {
            Addlabel(Address.Country);
        }
        Addlabel(String.Empty); // Notice the empty label...
    }

    private void Addlabel(String text)
    {            
        label = new Label();
        label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        label.Text = text;
        label.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        tlpAddress.Controls.Add(label, 1, tlpRowCount);
        tlpRowCount++;
    }
```

The `TableLayoutPanel` always gives me fits with size. In my example above, I'm filing an address card that might grow or shrink depending on the account having an address line two, or a country. Because the last row, or column, of the table layout panel will stretch, I throw the empty label in there to force a new empty row, then everything lines up nicely.

Here is the designer code so you can see the table I start with:

```
        //
        // tlpAddress
        // 
        this.tlpAddress.AutoSize = true;
        this.tlpAddress.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.tlpAddress.ColumnCount = 2;
        this.tlpAddress.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 25F));
        this.tlpAddress.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        this.tlpAddress.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1, 0, 0);
        this.tlpAddress.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.tlpAddress.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.tlpAddress.Name = "tlpAddress";
        this.tlpAddress.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tlpAddress.RowCount = 2;
        this.tlpAddress.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
        this.tlpAddress.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
        this.tlpAddress.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 95);
        this.tlpAddress.TabIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea for an empty placeholder row! Solved my sizing issues.

Answer (score 31):

It's a weird design, but the `TableLayoutPanel.RowCount` property doesn't reflect the count of the `RowStyles` collection, and similarly for the `ColumnCount` property and the `ColumnStyles` collection.

What I've found I needed in my code was to manually update `RowCount`/`ColumnCount` after making changes to `RowStyles`/`ColumnStyles`.

Here's an example of code I've used:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new row to our grid.
    /// </summary>
    /// The row should autosize to match whatever is placed within.
    /// <returns>Index of new row.</returns>
    public int AddAutoSizeRow()
    {
        Panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        Panel.RowCount = Panel.RowStyles.Count;
        mCurrentRow = Panel.RowCount - 1;
        return mCurrentRow;
    }
```

Other thoughts

- I've never used `DockStyle.Fill` to make a control fill a *cell* in the Grid; I've done this by setting the `Anchors` property of the control.
- If you're adding a lot of controls, make sure you call `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` around the process, else things will run slow as the entire form is relaid after each control is added.

Comment: If it's useful for anyone, in my case I had to call *tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();* when the form is loading.

Answer (score 17):

Here's my code for adding a new row to a two-column TableLayoutColumn:

```
private void AddRow(Control label, Control value)
{
    int rowIndex = AddTableRow();
    detailTable.Controls.Add(label, LabelColumnIndex, rowIndex);
    if (value != null)
    {
        detailTable.Controls.Add(value, ValueColumnIndex, rowIndex);
    }
}

private int AddTableRow()
{
    int index = detailTable.RowCount++;
    RowStyle style = new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize);
    detailTable.RowStyles.Add(style);
    return index;
}
```

The label control goes in the left column and the value control goes in the right column.  The controls are generally of type Label and have their AutoSize property set to true.

I don't think it matters too much, but for reference, here is the designer code that sets up detailTable:

```
this.detailTable.ColumnCount = 2;
this.detailTable.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
this.detailTable.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
this.detailTable.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.detailTable.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.detailTable.Name = "detailTable";
this.detailTable.RowCount = 1;
this.detailTable.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
this.detailTable.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(266, 436);
this.detailTable.TabIndex = 0;
```

This all works just fine.  You should be aware that there appear to be some problems with disposing controls from a TableLayoutPanel dynamically using the Controls property (at least in some versions of the framework).  If you need to remove controls, I suggest disposing the entire TableLayoutPanel and creating a new one.

Comment: This was very helpful. I found that the DockStyle.Fill attribute was essential. Also, it is surprisingly easy to make mistakes with the counting!  Also, note the column and row sizes set with styles. I found that when the RowStyle was set to AutoSize, some unintentional variations in the TextAlign settings (among Top, Middle, and Bottom) made it appear that the table was generating extra rows in some strange way, but that was not the case. The thing works pretty well once you figure it out, but it was painful getting there!

Answer (score 7):

Create a table layout panel with two columns in your form and name it `tlpFields`.

Then, simply add new control to table layout panel (in this case I added 5 labels in column-1 and 5 textboxes in column-2).

```
tlpFields.RowStyles.Clear();  //first you must clear rowStyles

for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
{
    Label l1= new Label();
    TextBox t1 = new TextBox();

    l1.Text = "field : ";

    tlpFields.Controls.Add(l1, 0, ii);  // add label in column0
    tlpFields.Controls.Add(t1, 1, ii);  // add textbox in column1

    tlpFields.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute,30)); // 30 is the rows space
}
```

Finally, run the code.

Comment: how you are accessing tlpfields? I have created tablelayoutpanel and its name is tabkelayout but i am unabla to access this.

Comment: @MuneemHabib go to tabkelayout properties and change **Modifiers** from private to public

Answer (score 4):

I just looked into my code. In one application, I just add the controls, but without specifying the index, and when done, I just loop through the row styles and set the size type to AutoSize. So just adding them without specifying the indices seems to add the rows as intended (provided the GrowStyle is set to AddRows).

In another application, I clear the controls and set the RowCount property to the needed value. This does not add the RowStyles. Then I add my controls, this time specifying the indices, and add a new RowStyle (`RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(...)`) and this also works.

So, pick one of these methods, they both work. I remember the headaches the table layout panel caused me.

Comment: I'll give these ones a try to see if it behaves itself!

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for adding rows and controls in a TableLayoutPanel.

Define a blank Tablelayoutpanel with 3 columns in the design page

```
    Dim TableLayoutPanel3 As New TableLayoutPanel()

    TableLayoutPanel3.Name = "TableLayoutPanel3"

    TableLayoutPanel3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(32, 287)

    TableLayoutPanel3.AutoSize = True

    TableLayoutPanel3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(620, 20)

    TableLayoutPanel3.ColumnCount = 3

    TableLayoutPanel3.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single

    TableLayoutPanel3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent

    TableLayoutPanel3.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 26.34146!))

    TableLayoutPanel3.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 73.65854!))

    TableLayoutPanel3.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 85.0!))

    Controls.Add(TableLayoutPanel3)
```

Create a button btnAddRow to add rows on each click

```
     Private Sub btnAddRow_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddRow.Click

          TableLayoutPanel3.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows

          TableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 20))

          TableLayoutPanel3.SuspendLayout()

          TableLayoutPanel3.RowCount += 1

          Dim tb1 As New TextBox()

          Dim tb2 As New TextBox()

          Dim tb3 As New TextBox()

          TableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(tb1 , 0, TableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1)

          TableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(tb2, 1, TableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1)

          TableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(tb3, 2, TableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1)

          TableLayoutPanel3.ResumeLayout()

          tb1.Focus()

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a related problem (which is how I found this thread), where my dynamically added row and column styles were not taking effect. I usually consider SuspendLayout()/ResumeLayout() as optimizations, but in this case, wrapping my code in them made the rows and columns behave correctly.

Answer (score -2):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dc As DataColumn
        dc = New DataColumn("Question", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add(dc)

        dc = New DataColumn("Ans1", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add(dc)
        dc = New DataColumn("Ans2", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add(dc)
        dc = New DataColumn("Ans3", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add(dc)
        dc = New DataColumn("Ans4", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add(dc)
        dc = New DataColumn("AnsType", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add(dc)


        Dim Dr As DataRow
        Dr = dt.NewRow
        Dr("Question") = "What is Your Name"
        Dr("Ans1") = "Ravi"
        Dr("Ans2") = "Mohan"
        Dr("Ans3") = "Sohan"
        Dr("Ans4") = "Gopal"
        Dr("AnsType") = "Multi"
        dt.Rows.Add(Dr)

        Dr = dt.NewRow
        Dr("Question") = "What is your father Name"
        Dr("Ans1") = "Ravi22"
        Dr("Ans2") = "Mohan2"
        Dr("Ans3") = "Sohan2"
        Dr("Ans4") = "Gopal2"
        Dr("AnsType") = "Multi"
        dt.Rows.Add(Dr)
        Panel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows
        Panel1.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.Azure
        Panel1.RowStyles.Insert(0, New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 50))
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For Each dri As DataRow In dt.Rows



            Dim lab As New Label()
            lab.Text = dri("Question")
            lab.AutoSize = True

            Panel1.Controls.Add(lab, 0, i)


            Dim Ans1 As CheckBox
            Ans1 = New CheckBox()
            Ans1.Text = dri("Ans1")
            Panel1.Controls.Add(Ans1, 1, i)

            Dim Ans2 As RadioButton
            Ans2 = New RadioButton()
            Ans2.Text = dri("Ans2")
            Panel1.Controls.Add(Ans2, 2, i)
            i = i + 1

            'Panel1.Controls.Add(Pan)
        Next
```

Comment: The question is about TableLayoutPanel, this post is about DataTable.  The post is code-only.  It doesn't have any text describing what the point might be.  No comments in the code either.  So, -1.