# Table Layout Control Position

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Controls in `TableLayoutPanel` get additional properties that are accessible in IDE. One is `Row` and another is `Column`, relative to `TableLayoutPanel`.

How do I get those properties' values by code?

I need to loop through all controls in my `TableLayoutPanel` and issue instructions based on their relative positions; but when I cast retrieved controls as a specific type, I don't get `Row` and `Column` properties.

Comment: You can look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142873/winforms-tablelayoutpanel-adding-rows-programatically), it may help you to access rows and columns of tablelayout from code

Comment: To what specific type(s) are you casting the controls in the `TableLayoutPanel`?  Some example code that demonstrates the problem you are having would help others to better understand and answer your question.

Comment: Use the TLP's GetRow() and GetColumn() methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it the other way around. Use `TableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(Control c)` method and pass your control to the method. Assign the return value to `TableLayoutPanelCellPosition` class variable. That object has `Row` and `Column` properties that return integer values.