# Having a certain layout when adding labels to a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm with a `Panel` and I keep adding `Labels` to it. Is it possible to set the `Panel` so that everytime I add a label it will have a certain layout ? The layout I am looking for is having a single column of `Labels`, so everytime I add a new `Label` it will be added to the next row. I haven't found any property for the `Panel` to do that. Is this possible ?

Comment: Are you adding it manually or programmatically ?

Comment: @voytek programmatically

Comment: Change the Y position of the newly created `Label` about `24px` different that one before or use a `Repeater` inside your `Panel` instead.

Comment: You can use TableLayoutPanel.you can find a good post [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142873/winforms-tablelayoutpanel-adding-rows-programatically

Comment: you can use TableLayoutPanel.you can find a good post [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142873/winforms-tablelayoutpanel-adding-rows-programatically

Comment: @TestWell This is not a very efficient method, as it will be a mess when adding labels in the begging of the panel for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FlowLayoutPanel` instead of Panel. And set the `FlowDirection` property to `TopDown`

Comment: I also had to change the `WrapContents` (last property) to false, so that the scrolling is vertical instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ListBox in the panel, and then add the Labels to it, rather than to panel directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TableLayoutPanel` and set its `ColumnCount` to 1.